# GWT - Prevent PDF file from being cached in IE?

Tags: java, pdf, caching, iframe, gwt

I have a GWT Web App (which requires a login) that calls a method on the Servlet (running in Tomcat) to generate a PDF file.  The Servlet returns a URL to the file and opens the PDF in an iFrame.

```
Frame frame = new Frame(reportUrl);
frame.show();
```

Upon closing the frame (or browser), a request is made to delete the file that was generated server side.  Now here is where the problem lies.  If I log out of the web application, and open a new tab in IE, it shows the URL in the history that was used to display the PDF.  Ideally this file is no longer accessible since it has been deleted on the server, and the user is no longer logged in, however the PDF still displays in the new tab.  I assume this is because the PDF file is being cached.

I am unable to reproduce this behavior in Chrome, so I assume the file either isn't being cached in Chrome, or Chrome just handles things a little differently.  Long story short, how do I make sure the file/url is no longer accessible once the user logs out of the web app?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically this is impossible, as you can't remotely clear the client-side cache. Also the user may have used `wget` or whatever to download the file so you can't assume information will be 100% inaccessible after the session has expired.

That being said, caching hints in the HTTP response headers can to some extent steer what a (well-behaved) client caches. As always implementation differs accross browsers. You can set HTTP headers either from your servlet directly in Java, or you can add them for instance from Apache HTTPD specifying cache headers for instance for all PDF downloads.

There are many resources on cache headers in HTTP, here's a good one: http://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/

I've also seen that HTTPS connections cause IE to be much stricter in what it caches, not sure if that is relevant/an option for you.